# How to do command substitution over SSH in one line

Tags: bash, ansible

I need to check the uptime of a remote_server if its lesser than 600 sec, if its greater than it then print passed else print fail. I know its possible using HERE docs but I need to do this in one line . Following are two failed attempts using shell one liner and HERE doc

Reason for using one line: I will feed the line to ansible's shell module. I tried following command and used single quotes to prevent expansion , but it is not working.

```
ssh remote_server "if [ '$(grep -oP \"^[0-9]+\" /proc/uptime)' -le 600 ];then echo  remote_server Failed ;exit 1;else echo remote_server passed ;fi"
```

I also tried following approach to convert if condition to multi line in ansible. but it is also not working.

```
  - name: get the uptime of all nodes
    shell:  |
    ssh {{ item }} " bash <<'EOF'
    if [ '$(grep -oP \"^[0-9]+\" /proc/uptime)' -le 600 ];then
        echo  {{ item }} Failed ;
        exit 1;
     else
        echo {{item }} passed ;
     fi
     "
     EOF
    with_items:
      - "{{ node_list.stdout_lines }}"
    become: true
```

The offending line appears to be:

```
       ssh {{ item }} " bash <<'EOF'
        if [ '$(grep -oP \"^[0-9]+\" /proc/uptime)' -le 600 ];then
        ^ here

exception type: <class 'yaml.scanner.ScannerError'>
exception: while scanning a simple key
  in "<unicode string>", line 51, column 9
could not find expected ':'
  in "<unicode string>", line 52, column 9
```

Update:

```
 shell:  ssh {{ item }} 'if [ "$(grep -oP '^[0-9]+' /proc/uptime) -le 600 ]; then echo failed; exit 1; else echo passed; fi'
```

Error:

```
"start": "2019-02-07 15:05:36.740756",
"stderr": "bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `\"'\nbash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file",
"stderr_lines": [
    "bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `\"'",
    "bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file"
],
"stdout": "",
"stdout_lines": []
```

Comment: The outer level of double-quotes is allowing `$(grep ...)` to be expanded on the local computer; even if that hadn't happened, the single-quotes inside it would prevent it from being expanded on the remote computer. You need to swap single- and double-quotes, something like this: `ssh remote_server 'if [ "$(grep -oP \"^[0-9]+\" /proc/uptime)" -le 600 ];then echo  remote_server Failed ;exit 1;else echo remote_server passed ;fi'`. Note that this quoting is appropriate for a command being typed at a shell prompt; using it in ansible may complicate things if it doesn't parse quite the same.

Comment: after swapping they are conflicting with single quotes of `EOF`

Comment: getting it in shell is understood, but feeding it to ansible is problem

Comment: At the very least, the `EOF` needs to be *inside* the double quotes. You don't really need a here document anyway; `ssh {{ item }} 'if [ "$(grep ...) -le 600 ]; then echo ...; exit 1; else echo ..; fi'`.

Comment: @chepner updated the question with the error output resulted from your suggestion

Comment: @monk Typo; I didn't close the double quote after closing the command substitution. `"$(...)"`, not `"$(...)`.

Comment: Thank you Chepner ,its working now!!! you can put it in answer